# Get list of directories with more than 20,000 files/subdirectories

Tags: find

I want to get a list with all the directories that contains more than 20,000 files/subdirectories.

For example:

```
Folder A
|_ Folder A1
  |_ Folder A11
    |_ 25,000 files
  |_ 15,000 files
|_ Folder A2
  |_ 21,000 files
|_ 10 files
```

I want to get the following list:

```
Folder A11
Folder A2
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of names in a directory may be counted using `set -- *`.  The count is then found in `$#`.

With `find`, you may execute the `set` command and test the value of `$#` in a short in-line shell script:

```bash
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
    for dirpath do
        set -- "$dirpath"/*
        [ "$#" -gt 20000 ] && printf "%s\n" "$dirpath"
    done' sh {} +
```

The inline `sh -c` script will get batches of found directory pathnames as arguments.  The script iterates over a batch of these pathnames and expands the `*` glob in each.  If the resulting list contains strictly more than 20000 strings, the directory pathname is outputted using `printf`.

To also count *hidden* names, you may want to switch to calling the `bash` shell with its `dotglob` shell option set:

```bash
find . -type d -exec bash -O dotglob -c '
    for dirpath do
        set -- "$dirpath"/*
        [ "$#" -gt 20000 ] && printf "%s\n" "$dirpath"
    done' bash {} +
```

Note that if you want to *do* something to these directories, you'd be best served if you do that as part of the inline script above (rather than, say, [try to parse the output of the `find` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)):

```bash
find . -type d -exec bash -O dotglob -c '
    for dirpath do
        set -- "$dirpath"/*
        [ "$#" -gt 20000 ] || continue

        # Process "$dirpath" here

    done' bash {} +
```

Comment: What should I write in dirpath? my dir path?

Comment: @STF The commands, as given, will operate on the current directory (and it will recursively descend into subdirectories). If you need to point the `find` command elsewhere, then change the `.` after `find` to the desired top-level directory.  Do not modify `dirpath` in the script, it's a variable that the script uses and its values will be provided by `find`.

Comment: ♦ I tried the script in one line and got: 
 find . -type d -exec sh -c 'for dirpath do set -- "$dirpath"/* [ "$#" -gt 20000 ] && printf "%s\n" "$dirpath" done' bash {} +
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @STF Yes, that is expected. You will have to add a few semi-colons if you want to fold it into a single line: `find . -type d -exec sh -c 'for dirpath do set -- "$dirpath"/*; [ "$#" -gt 20000 ] && printf "%s\n" "$dirpath"; done' sh {} +`